# Stop a SQL route in Apache Camel

Tags: java, oracle, elasticsearch, apache-camel

I'm currently trying to import some data from Oracle to ElasticSearch (in JSON format) using Apache Camel. I'm totally new on this framework, so I was thinking that you might help with it !

Here is my code :

```
from("sql://select log_instance_id, calculated_status, begin_date, end_date, mediation_descr_code, duration from of_log_mediation_instance?dataSource=myDataSource")
.to("elasticsearch://boa-elasticsearch?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet")
```

The problem is that the route never stop because I call it with a from("sql: select ...") It finished the first time, then rerun the route until I stop the context at the end of a Thread.sleep(10000). I've tried to begin with other endpoints but I often have this error :

```
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest with value [{LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4029927, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-21 16:54:31.45436, END_DATE=2015-05-21 16:54:31.495735, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=0.041}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4140006, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowCompleted, BEGIN_DATE=2015-06-01 11:11:31.569414, END_DATE=2015-06-01 11:11:33.109604, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=RecevoirDemOpeContrat, DURATION=1.54}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4038409, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-22 10:18:11.295776, END_DATE=2015-05-22 10:18:11.299125, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=0.004}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4144321, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowCompleted, BEGIN_DATE=2015-06-01 15:33:12.37841, END_DATE=2015-06-01 15:33:12.822529, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=RecevoirDemOpeContrat, DURATION=0.444}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4039159, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-22 11:23:56.462823, END_DATE=2015-05-22 11:23:58.15667, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=1.694}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4045264, CALCULATED_STATUS=... [Body clipped after 1000 chars, total length is 16546230] due java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:571)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:129)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:72)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:47)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.process(ElasticsearchProducer.java:116)[camel-elasticsearch-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:87)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:56)[camel-quartz2-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)[quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)[quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] CamelJob                       ERROR Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [{LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4029927, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-21 16:54:31.45436, END_DATE=2015-05-21 16:54:31.495735, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=0.041}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4140006, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowCompleted, BEGIN_DATE=2015-06-01 11:11:31.569414, END_DATE=2015-06-01 11:11:33.109604, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=RecevoirDemOpeContrat, DURATION=1.54}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4038409, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-22 10:18:11.295776, END_DATE=2015-05-22 10:18:11.299125, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=0.004}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4144321, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowCompleted, BEGIN_DATE=2015-06-01 15:33:12.37841, END_DATE=2015-06-01 15:33:12.822529, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=RecevoirDemOpeContrat, DURATION=0.444}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4039159, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-22 11:23:56.462823, END_DATE=2015-05-22 11:23:58.15667, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=1.694}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4045264, CALCULATED_STATUS=... [Body clipped after 1000 chars, total length is 16546230]]. Caused by: [org.quartz.JobExecutionException - org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest with value [{LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4029927, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-21 16:54:31.45436, END_DATE=2015-05-21 16:54:31.495735, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=0.041}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4140006, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowCompleted, BEGIN_DATE=2015-06-01 11:11:31.569414, END_DATE=2015-06-01 11:11:33.109604, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=RecevoirDemOpeContrat, DURATION=1.54}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4038409, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-22 10:18:11.295776, END_DATE=2015-05-22 10:18:11.299125, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=0.004}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4144321, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowCompleted, BEGIN_DATE=2015-06-01 15:33:12.37841, END_DATE=2015-06-01 15:33:12.822529, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=RecevoirDemOpeContrat, DURATION=0.444}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4039159, CALCULATED_STATUS=flowError, BEGIN_DATE=2015-05-22 11:23:56.462823, END_DATE=2015-05-22 11:23:58.15667, MEDIATION_DESCR_CODE=DiffuserMAJOfrCial, DURATION=1.694}, {LOG_INSTANCE_ID=4045264, CALCULATED_STATUS=... [Body clipped after 1000 chars, total length is 16546230] due java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

I've tried direct, quartz scheluder, .end(), loop(1), ...

Thank you !

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Run the import only once? Or run it every X min/sec?

Comment: At the end, I would like to run it every X time, but for the moment, if I can do it only once, it would be great !

Comment: `elasticsearch` requires Map as input, result of your query is a `List<Map<K,V>>`. Try passing Map to elastic search end point.

Comment: Yes, but it also accept List of Map to create Bulk request which are faster than execute operation one by one ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run it every X time, try timer component

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000")
    .to("sql://select log_instance_id, calculated_status, begin_date, end_date, mediation_descr_code, duration from of_log_mediation_instance?dataSource=myDataSource")
    .to("elasticsearch://boa-elasticsearch?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet")
```

This route will run every 1 minute. If you need more complex logic, try quartz component

```
from("quartz://foo/bar?cron=0+0/1+*+*+*+?")
    .to("sql://select log_instance_id, calculated_status, begin_date, end_date, mediation_descr_code, duration from of_log_mediation_instance?dataSource=myDataSource")
    .to("elasticsearch://boa-elasticsearch?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet")
```

Comment: I've already tried that and I still have the same error, it can't do the conversion with the String because of a NullPointerException.. I don't know why the timer could influence the return of the SQL query..